# Login validation with database

Tags: sql, delphi, ado, delphi-2010

**PROBLEM**

Hello! I need to make login in Delphi 2010. I have MS Access database where I have fields (loginID, username, password). So I have 2 TEdit components for username and password. I have connected to database in delphi and all connections are working.

So problem is that I don't know how to check if text from TEdit is in database. I need something like query.

Example:

```
if Edit1.Text in login.username then

something

else

something else
```

Hope you understand what I need, but anyway you can ask a questions for more information. I will be thankful for solution.

**WHAT I TRYED**

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT FROM login WHERE username = :Edit1.Text';
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

I don't know if it works.

How to check like this:

```
if ADOQuery1 execute then

something

else

something else
```

Comment: You need to use an ADO query with parameters and check to see if the user exists using a SELECT. How to use TADOQuery is in the Delphi [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/ADODB.TADOQuery), and how to use a SELECT is in your SQL manual.

Comment: Check my last update in question please. And can you tell me how to check if query is true (if it works) or false?

Comment: I just did. Don't be so impatient. You need to give people time to write their answers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly parameterize your query, and use the Parameters. (You also need to write valid SQL, which for a SELECT requires a list of columns you want returned.)

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT UserName FROM login WHERE username = :User';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('User').Value := Edit1.Text;
```

You then need to open (not execute) the query, and see if it returned a value.

```
ADOQuery1.Open;
if not ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
begin
  // User exists. Do whatever you need next.
end
else
  // Do what you want if user not found
```

I'd strongly suggest that if you're going to try and use databases, you buy a book or find a tutorial. `SELECT` is one of the most basic operations you'll need to perform.

Comment: `[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(52): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Empty'` problem with `ADOQuery1.Empty` I think.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. It's `IsEmpty` instead.

Comment: Also I have question.. I can make multiple query's using one `ADOQuery` component or for each query I need different component?

Comment: One component, changing the SQL. You really should read the documentation. :-(

Comment: I have learned about Delphi, I just don't know about components what I didn't used when i was studying.. So I just ask because its more easier to say yes or no, not like searching in google and trying to find by my self... But anyway thanks...

Comment: StackOverflow is supposed to be used *last*, after you've searched yourself and studied, not *first* before you do anything yourself. You'll get yourself in trouble here if you forget that fact. :-)

Comment: You should use one query component for each query. You don't have to but this will lead to the golden ring pattern: "One query component to rule them all". It is the same with each component: Do you need more than one button, one edit, one form, ... it depends on your application.

Comment: @SirRufo: Using one per query quickly becomes unmanageable at times. For instance, I have one application that performs about 200 different queries during a typical hour, often just for lookup operations. My datamodule has roughly 60 query components used for those where prepared queries will be useful, and a handful of "general purpose* query components that are used and reused for the others. Having 200 query components on the DM would just be a nightmare even trying to find one to edit the SQL.

Comment: @KenWhite For dynamic queries I use dynamic query components

Comment: @SirRufo: So do I for some things. It's often useful to have a few `QryMisc` type components around that you don't have to create/configure/use/free over and over again.

Comment: @KenWhite I use a method for the creation and configuration (and setting parameters) part. So it is just use and free and of course DRY